# How to make non-body scrollbar transparent with CSS? (works fine on body)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar

### Problem:

In the following code sample, why is the scrollbar on the left not transparent like the scrollbar on the right?

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

/* make the scrollbar cover the content */
.sidebar,
body {
  /* Make the scrollbar draw on top of content in Webkit browsers. */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

/* now make it transparent (no luck here) */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.3) !important;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) !important;
}



.sidebar {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}

.sidebar p {
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
}

div {
  padding-left: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">aside
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven
  </p>
  <p>
</aside>

<main>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
  <div>
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
  </div>
</main>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

### Expected result:

Both the sidebar (left) and body (right) scrollbars should be transparent, and you should see content underneath both of them.

### Actual result:

Only the body scrollbar is transparent, while the sidebar scrollbar does not seem to have transparency and we can not see the sidebar content underneath the sidebar's scrollbar.

### Question

How can we make the sidebar scrollbar transparent and show the content underneath?

Comment: did you reset overflow to hidden (and height) on HTML to allow body to take over ? our bits of code are not enough to reproduce your issue : https://jsfiddle.net/odkLcu8z/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus It looks like you reproduced the issue in your fiddle: although the color of the scrollbar elements has transparency, the `<p>` content is not visible behind it. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks, I updated my question with a simple reproduction forked from your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To make transparent of the sidebar scrollbar, you need to target the sidebar element and apply css code.

```
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
}
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.3) !important;
}
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) !important;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for sidebar transparent. Thank you dude!

Comment: It isn't working for me. I updated my question with a screenshot showing the results that I see. I tried targetting both `.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar...` and `*::-webkit-scrollbar...` but either way the sidebar scrollbar is not transparent (see screenshot).

Comment: @Kenny Are you saying that for you, the sidebar scrollbar is transparent? Can you show a screenshot?